# Cancel ADM Reset

Tags: google

My phone was recently stolen so I used ADM to reset everything but this afternoon I found the bugger who took it and retrieved it the problem is when I connect to the wifi it will wipe everything is there anyway to tell ADM not to reset?

Comment: You want us to say "Yes", but how would Google know the request was legitimately from you? It can't make those distinctions, so their position has been "No", Not cancelled.

Comment: @wbogacz Kind of. Wouldn't removing the Google account before connecting the device to any network take care of that? No Google account, no access by ADM.

Comment: @Izzy - I don't know, but that seems like TOO easy a defeat of the process. But we could tire ourselves debating this as 3rd party observers without clarity or certainty. It would be to Google's advantage to keep the actual workings obscured, so its process can't be beaten.

Comment: @wbogacz to "beat" it that way still requires to unlock the device. And I'm pretty sure ADM cannot access any device without the Google account. Not 100%, but close to.